# How to list programmable wake devices with C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, power-management

I'm trying to achieve the results of the following command that lists all programmable wake devices, or those that can be set/reset to wake the system:

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_programmable
```

I need to do the same from a C++ service. I'm using the code similar to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it gives me a smaller list. Here's how I call `DevicePowerEnumDevices`:

```
if(DevicePowerEnumDevices(index,
    DEVICEPOWER_FILTER_DEVICES_PRESENT,
    PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D0_SUPPORTED |
    PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D1_SUPPORTED |
    PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D2_SUPPORTED |
    PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D3_SUPPORTED |
    PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_S0_SUPPORTED |
    PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_S1_SUPPORTED | 
    PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_S2_SUPPORTED |
    PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_S3_SUPPORTED,
    buff, &dwBuffSize))
{
    //Got it
}
```

What flags am I missing for `wake_programmable`?

Comment: Strange. If I use your code, I get a much bigger list than the one given by powercfg -devicequery wake_programmable

Comment: @manuell: Hmm. Did you find a set of flags to match `powercfg -devicequery wake_programmable`?

Comment: No, sorry (I would have answered :-)